# How to disable or change colors from tox output

Tags: python, tox

When using tox by default it will output colours to the terminal which is actually fine if you using a white background terminal but hard to see with a dark terminal. Is there any tricks to disable colours in tox without hacking the code directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TERM=dumb on the command line if you want to disable the colors but don't know about changing the colors.